# Running Saxon from a batch file: how do I capture errors?

Tags: batch-file, saxon

I've got a batch file that calls Saxon to do an XSLT transformation. For some files, Saxon gives me an error. This appears in a new command line window which is open for about 1 second, and then closes. I'm trying to capture that error message in a file.

This is the relevant part of the batch file:

```
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.6N\bin\Transform.exe" -s:"file.xml" -xsl:fixerrors.xslt -o:"output.xml" 1>>fixerrors.log 2>&1
```

The fixerrors.log file is created, but remains empty even if Saxon encounters an error and creates the new command line window.

I was able to capture error messages from another program like this, so the idea of using `1>>fixerrors.log` is not wrong in itself. This seems to be specific to Saxon.

Comment: try this and see if it opens a log with content.. `start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.6N\bin\Transform.exe" -s:"file.xml" -xsl:fixerrors.xslt -o:"output.xml"  >fixerrors.log 2>&1 & type fixerrors.log & pause` It should also keep the window open for you to see errors.

Comment: also, you should not need to use start, you could just call the path and executable alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried two approaches suggested by @Gerhard Barnard:

```
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.6N\bin\Transform.exe" -s:"%~n1 - original.xml" -xsl:fixerrors.xslt -o:"%~n1.xml" 1>>fixerrors.log 2>&1 & type fixerrors.log
```

does not work, the Saxon errors are not placed in the log file.

```
"C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.6N\bin\Transform.exe" -s:"%~n1 - original.xml" -xsl:fixerrors.xslt -o:"%~n1.xml" 1>>fixerrors.log 2>&1
```

does work, the error messages are placed in the log file (in fact, they're placed twice because I'm redirecting both standard error and standard output to the file).